# Storedprocedure returns xml but linq replaces ' " ' with '\'

Tags: xml, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in sql server that returns xml. The problem I'm facing is that the returned result which is of type ISingleResult contains the string for the xml returned by the stored procedure and in this string all the '  " ' are replaced by '\'.

So I can't parse the xml.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This is the code

  MyDataContext ctx = new MyDataContext ();
   

            

            ISingleResult<SP_MySP>  x = ctx.SP_MYSP();

            foreach (SP_MySP rslt in x)
            {
                xmlstring = xmlstring + rslt.XML_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B;
            }


This xml string object contains \ character instead of double quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False Alarm guys.

The \ was and escape character.  It shows up in tehe debugger but not when I do a Write Line.

These threads helped

[C# String.Replace double quotes and Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285579/c-string-replace-double-quotes-and-literals)